# When copy constructor starts working?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass {
public:
     myclass();
     myclass(const myclass &o);
     myclass f();
};
myclass:: myclass(){
    cout<<"Constructing normally"<<endl;
};
myclass:: myclass(const myclass &o){
    cout<<"Constructing copy"<<endl;
};
myclass myclass::f(){
    myclass temp;
    return temp;
};
int main(){
   myclass obj;
   obj = obj.f();
   return 0;
}
```

I found this example in a book which shows that the output of the program should be:

```
Constructing normally
Constructing normally
Constructing copy
```

But when i compile it in my compiler it only shows the output written below

```
Constructing normally
Constructing normally
```

What is actually happening inside?

Comment: it means your compiler has optimised the copy away for the second line `obj = obj.f();`

Comment: i couldn't get it :(.Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Read about return value optimization and copy elision (your book might be old).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: Your compiler decided that the copy was unnecessary so it just removed it as it decided it could construct normally and assign directly without involving the copy

Comment: I've reopened: I can't find an exact dupe that explains why one of the copies *can't* be optimised out but the other *can* be.

Comment: @EdChum: This is not entirely correct. The compiler *cannot* optimise out due to the constructor side effect. But it is allowed to exploit NRVO.

Comment: @Bathsheba OK I originally thought this was copy ellision but your answer explains the difference here

Answer (score 11):

Your constructor has a *side effect* - namely the `cout` call. So the compiler *cannot* optimise out the copy taken in `obj = obj.f();`.

But the C++ standard *does* allow it to optimise out the deep copy taken in

```
myclass myclass::f(){
    myclass temp;
    return temp;
};
```

*despite* there being a side effect. That allowable strategy is called *Named Return Value Optimisation*.

Sadly your book is really rather outdated, or factually incorrect from the outset! You could use it for kindling when lighting those cosy fires this coming winter.

Comment: Sunny, you said !?

Comment: @GillBates: Ha. I had to come back into the office. Now I'm compiling something.

Comment: You mean "Now I'm waiting for my computer to do all the hard work while I'm sipping coffee" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass {
public:
 myclass();
myclass(const myclass &o);
myclass f();
};
myclass:: myclass(){
cout<<"Constructing normally"<<endl;
};
myclass:: myclass(const myclass &o){
cout<<"Constructing copy"<<endl;
};
myclass myclass::f(){
myclass *temp;
return *temp;
};
int main(){
myclass obj;
obj = obj.f();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this it will give the output:Constructing normally and Constructing copy